# Different letters for shared drives

Tags: vba, excel

**Quick Background:** I write excel macros for a company that uses shared drives on the network to share information between employees

**The Problem:** Different employees have the same shared drive listed under separate letters. For example Susie has the "Commissions Shared Drive" as drive "Z" but Betty has it as drive "x".

I'll design a macro that two different people use and the macro runs into errors because they have separate drive letters. **To put it simply, the file locations written in the code won't be correct for both people due to the difference of drive letter.**

**The Current Solution:** I currently have a copy of the exact same macro with changes made to the file locations to account for the difference of drive letter. This is annoying because anytime I make changes to the one file I have to ensure the other is exactly the same.

**The Question:** Is there a way I can account for different drive letters in one macro so I don't have to have duplicates of the file with different addresses?

Thanks in Advance!

-Mike

Comment: At the risk of getting flamed... if you do a search for "get unc path vba" in your favorite search engine, there are several pages with code samples that show you how to convert a given path to a UNC path. You can then use that path in your program so anyone who has access to the drive can get there.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy I'll check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the actual network path.

For instance instead of something like

```
Z:\filename
```

Use

```
\\servername\foldername\filename
```

As long as the user has access to the path, the code will find it regardless of drive mapping.

Edit:
You can view [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/393397/why-is-it-bad-to-map-network-drives-in-windows) and its answers for some great reasons why you should not use the mapped drive letters in your code.
As a side note, if you were using something less updatable then an Excel macro, it would be a good idea to not actually store the path in your code at all. Instead you would have a file that the code views to obtain the path. Thereby what you write will work far longer without having to be recompiled or revised. But again, since you're just doing an Excel macro I see no compelling reason not to use the direct path.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Cook I also found another path that you can use to refer to a shared drive.

If you right click on the shared drive and go to properties > DFS (DFS is a tab in the properties window) they list a separate path there that works. I created a macro to test both paths and both worked.

However, one of my associates said he made a macro for another employee using the path method of \servername\foldername\filename and it didn't work on her computer for some reason, but when he used the other pathway found in the DFS tab under the shared drive's properties it worked for her.

Any ideas why the \servername\foldername\filename path might work on one computer and not another?

Comment: They probably have different administrator privileges.

Comment: you may be right about that..I'm going to try and research a little to see what I can find.